# Javascript popup window doesn't gain focus after first load in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup, focus

Easiest way to explain should be this example http://www.massimofidanza.it/firefox . This works correctly (popup is focussed again) only on IE. Is there any workaround (without closing and opening a new popup)?
update: option for javascript to raise popup windows is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

make w a global variable.  When the popup link is clicked, check if w exists and if it exists, close it and open the other popup...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var w;
function openPopup(purl)
{
    wndAttr = "width=500,height=400,left=100,top=100";

    if(w) 
    {
        w.close();
    }
    w = window.open(purl, 'popup_test', wndAttr);
    w.focus();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this wont't help in this case. Popup contains flash movie that shouldn't be reloaded, so I cant close and open the popup. Any other suggestions?